# Is there a way to programmatically launch edge with default search engine?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have been investigating ways to launch edge with default search engine. I am aware of microsoft-edge protocol but I need to specify the search engine explicitly(for example : "microsoft-edge:https://bing.com?&q=") to be used. I was wondering if there is way to launch edge by just passing query, such that default search engine associated to the browser is launched with the query term?

I did try start msedge "Barack+Obama" through command prompt and I observe the query term in the address bar but the web page is broken (maybe since it excepts url): [image]

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this. Edge only opens urls. Why does it have to be the default?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the way I complete it is a bit tricky. It involves writing a `.bat` file.

**Step 1**

Write a `.bat` file. Use the following code (Bing as an example):

```
@echo off

set query=%1%
start msedge https://www.bing.com/search?q=%query%
```

Then, add the `.bat` file directory to the `PATH` Environment Variable so you're able to call it with `start` command.

**PS:** Remember to rename the file with a cool name. I renamed the `.bat` file "MyEdge".

**Step 2**

In Command Prompt, use `start MyEdge stackoverflow` (or anything you'd like to search). Then, you should see the Bing search result of stackoverflow.

**PS:** You may see a **ghost** command prompt after executing `.bat` file. To avoid that, you can convert the `.bat` file into a `.exe` file and replace the former.